# Way to diff two SQL CE Databases

Tags: t-sql, scripting, sql-server-ce

I know ways to script a SQL CE Database, but does anyone know a way to diff two databases and output a script sync one of them to the other (ie generate drops and inserts to make them the same).

I am looking for a way that I can update my hand held applications without having to copy over the existing database.  The first step is to be able to make a change script.

Comment: This is not enough information to understand what you are doing; by "script" do you mean SQL DDL statements? Shell scripts? Installer scripts? What are you "diff"ing? Schemas? SQL statements? Data rows? Column values? Define "update". Are you changing data values? Schemas? Both? Are you trying to update existing, running in the field data? Or are you leaving existing data as is and creating a new app? Question is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Script the two SQL CE databases, and load them into 2 SQL Server Express tables, and use one of the many SQL Server compare tools to compare these.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to copy changes in a local SQLS CE database to another local CE database? Or are you trying to replicate changes between multiple CE clients with internet access? If the latter, check out SQLS CE [Merge Replication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172367%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx).

Comment: I am trying to be able to roll out a new version of my database with out having to overwrite the database (on a local sql ce db).  The hope was to make it part of my build process (just output a change script that can be run on the client machine).  I will take a look at Merge Replication just in case it can help me.